# Docker + MySQL -- The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it

Tags: mysql, docker

I think I've tried every solution on related issues going back a few years, coming in with this issue with some slightly different parameters / versions.

**What I'm working with:**

macOS Monterey
version 12.7.1
MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, Early 2016)
Processor 1.1 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core m3

Docker Desktop Version
4.25.0 (126437)

**Among the things I've tried:**

- Changing ownership and permissions.
- Editing File Sharing in the Resources list in Docker Desktop.
- Uninstalling and reinstalling `mysql` (via Brew).
- Editing the commands in the `docker-compose.yml`

*This repo / container works on my colleagues' machines, but they have M1 MacBooks.*

**The terminal output in question:**

```
appname-mysql  | 2023-11-10T21:43:03.363441Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
appname-mysql  | 2023-11-10T21:43:03.363657Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
appname-mysql  | 2023-11-10T21:43:03.363978Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.2.0)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
appname-mysql  | 2023-11-10T21:43:03.364727Z 0 [System] [MY-015018] [Server] MySQL Server Initialization - end.
```

**Relevant part of the docker-compose.yml:**

```
  db:
    container_name: appname-mysql
    image: mysql:8
    restart: always
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-dumps:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
```

Open to trying anything here. This is a personal machine, not a managed device, if that makes a difference. Just trying to get a local dev setup working!

Answer (score 0):

Do what it asks "The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it".

To do so:

```
command: rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/*
```

Then change it back. `mysqld` is also unneeded in `command`, options are sufficient.

Aside: Are you sure you want to be using 8.2.0, its very new?

Comment: Thanks! Got that `docker-compose.yml` from someone on the team, didn't really know if it was a safe thing to edit.